# SpeechSynthezier.PhonemeReached event and control characters

Tags: .net, speechsynthesizer, speech-synthesis

I am creating a small silverlight widget which pronounces a word and highlights each syllable as it is pronounced.

As part of this, I am using the [SpeechSynthesizer.PhonemeReached event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.phonemereached.aspx) to determine the start and end times of each phoneme (as a step in figuring out the start and end times of each syllable).

The weird thing is that the [PhonemeReachedEventArgs.Phoneme property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.phonemereachedeventargs.phoneme.aspx) is sometimes a control character, at least (but possibly not exclusively) [U+0004 END OF TRANSMISSION](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0004/index.htm), including places which are not, umm, the end of the transmission (like, say, the beginning).

I can't find any documentation of what this is supposed to mean, does anyone know?

**EDIT**: To clarify, I'm not doing the speech synthesis in Silverlight (since that isn't supported), I am doing it on the server and returning the syllable boundary times and IPA transcription of the word in an HTTP header of the audio response. I probably shouldn't have mentioned the silverlight part at all, since it isn't really relevant, I just didn't really think much about explaining the context. Ooops. :)

Comment: How are you using that library in Silverlight since it isn't a Silverlight library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to figure out the start and end times of each phoneme (which really is a different question)... try using the PhonemeReachedEventArgs.Duration property. The start time will be the "start time of the phrase" + the cumulative durations of all previously pronounced phonemes. The end time will be the "start time of the current phoneme" + the duration of the current phoneme.

As to answer your "posted" question, I am assuming that you are using English as your language of synthesis. In this case, it is likely that the "characters" you are seeing are actually index values to the [American English Phoneme Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717239(VS.85).aspx). You may also see the same with [Chinese phonemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720566(VS.85).aspx), however [Japanese phonemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720568(VS.85).aspx) have unicode representations, which are all outside of the "control character" range.

Comment: I don't think that these characters are indexes into that table, because they don't match the values in the "SYM" column there, and some are Unicode IPA Extensions characters like U+0254 and U+026a.

Thanks, though, I wasn't aware of that set of documents.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now, they are indexes into that table. I misread.